# How can I update MacBook Air Lion when I can't review Apple ID with El Capitan?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, software-update

My wife has bought a used MacBook Air with macOS 10.7.5 and needs to update to allow installation of a couple of apps.

The problem:

1. Cannot update macOS from App Store without reviewing Apple ID
2. Cannot review Apple ID without updating macOS

I've tried adding myself as a new user with Admin. privileges, but the same problem occurs.

Neither of us have any other Apple devices, and we don't use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 'inherit' anything on a new [used] Mac you bought.

You must 'nuke & pave' - wipe it & start over.
The seller ought to have done this before parting with it - because everything on there belongs to the seller, including the OS itself.

Full instructions at Apple KB - [What to do before you sell or give away your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065)
If you have no contact with the original owner, you have to start from Step 6 [& hope they had the sense to do the first 5].